# How to discard the change set once delivered in RTC

Tags: rtc, rational-team-concert

I accidentally delivered the change set which include some additional config files having local system specific configuration in RTC. Is there any way to discard those changes once delivered? I mean the changes should not be come as incoming changes to other team members.

Please provide any pointer if you have.

Answer (score 10):

> Is there any way to discard those changes once delivered?

Not exactly: once delivered, that change set *will* come to the other team members as incoming.

There are two solutions:

- revert the stream configuration to a state previous to your deliver. That is easy only if you are delivering baselines in addition of change sets, because you can then open the stream, and in the "component" section click on "Replace with", and replace the delivered baseline with the previous one.

But... if you never delivered baselines (and delivered only change sets), this isn't easy at all.
You can try and follow "[Is there a way to create a RTC snapshot or baseline based on a past date?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17658195/6309)", but that is quite tedious.
Plus, if your colleagues already accepted your change set and started delivering change sets of their own, this solution isn't recommended at all.

- Or, much simpler, you create a new changeset which will cancel the one you just deliver.

  - Right-click on your component, and select `show > history`, then right click on the latest change set you incorrectly delivered, and select **`revert`**.
    That will create a patch.
  - Right-click on that patch, and select "`apply to your workspace`": that will create a change set which is the negative image of the one already delivered.
    Deliver that new change set.

That means your colleagues will have to accept *both* change sets: the incorrect one, and the new one which cancels it.

---

[This thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/81423/how-to-roll-back-remove-delivered-change-sets-in-rtc?redirect=/forum/questions/81423/how-to-roll-back-remove-delivered-change-sets-in-rtc) introduces a variation of the first alternative:

> you can really remove the change set from the stream you delivered it to.
>   You can do this by:
>
> - discarding the change set from your local workspace
> - and then replacing the content of the stream with the content of your workspace for the particular component that's affected.
>
> This is a more risky solution, because it *really* replaces the content of the stream with whatever you have in your workspace...  it will remove anything in the stream that you don't have in your workspace. To do this:
>
> - a. Accept any incoming changes from the stream you are working with (to prevent losing anyone else's work).
> - b. Right click on the owning component in the `Pending Changes` view and select `Show->History`. The change set will appear in the `History` view.
> - c. Right click on the change set and choose `Discard`... This will discard the change set from your workspace.
>     So your workspace should now have all change from the stream *except* the one you want to remove. You can verify this by checking that your bad change set is the only thing you see Incoming.
> - d. Right click on the component and choose "`Replace in [your stream name]`..."