# discard change set from workspace

Tags: rtc, jazz, ibm-jazz

I am completely new using RTC so please, I need an answer as simple as possible.

I recently accepted a change set from another team member and I need to discard the change set from my workspace. My problem here is that the change set I accepted was not delivered and it's still pending and awaiting a review approval. If I discard the change set will this wipe out the team members changes or will it just remove the change set from my workspace? In other words, I am not going to remove any changes the other team member made am I?

I really need to understand this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> If I discard the change set will this wipe out the team members changes or will it just remove the change set from my workspace?

Just from your workspace (and your repo workspace).
See help page "[Discarding change sets from workspaces](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=//com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/t_discarding_change_set.html)".

Once a change set is delivered to the stream, you cannot remove it.
And you will have to accept it eventually, especially if you want to deliver your own change sets yourself to that same stream.

If accepting that change set is problematic, then the developer who originally delivered that activity to the stream needs to revert it (deliver a new change set that would cancel the previous one).
See more at "[How to discard the change set once delivered in RTC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21951233/6309)".

---

[Erigami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/158490/erigami) comments [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22622171/discard-change-set-from-workspace/22626723?noredirect=1#comment34851628_22626723):

> You can remove a change set from a stream by:
>
> 1. discarding it from your workspace, then
> 2. running 'Replace in `<stream name>`' from the Pending Changes view.
>
> That sets the component's history to be the same as that of your workspace, so make sure you have all of the change sets you want in there. ;)

Comment: You can remove a change set from a stream by: (1) discarding it from your workspace, then (2) running 'Replace in <stream name>' from the Pending Changes view. That sets the component's history to be the same as that of your workspace, so make sure you have all of the change sets you want in there. ;)

Comment: @Erigami good point. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.