# New RTC stream from existing baseline / Truncate history

Tags: rational-team-concert

We're trying to migrate RTC to Git with tons of change sets which takes too long.  While we can use a flavor of RTC2GIT with a baseline starting point, I also want to try a migration from a new RTC Stream that has been created without all the old history prior to a given baseline.  We would choose our first baseline that is a few years old (several thousand changesets), as opposed to the 10+ years of change set history (100k+) that we have.  It's a simplification because some activities are too slow in the tools.

To start with, how can we create a new RTC Stream from an existing stream's baseline without the prior changesets?  I see that after selecting a component, I can use Replace with... and choose a baseline.  That resets my workspace component to that baseline.  So what is the most efficient way to create a new stream from that reset Workspace but without all the changesets (such that if we list the history there is none)?

After that starting point in the new stream, hopefully I could use the original stream as the flow target in my workspace to accept every changeset from the baseline forward to the current date.  Then the new stream would have all changesets from the baseline to now, which is the desired goal.  For reference see: [Is there a way to create a RTC snapshot or baseline based on a past date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657856/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-rtc-snapshot-or-baseline-based-on-a-past-date)

Ideally it would be nice to use a starting date even older than our first baseline (few years old), to create the new stream but I don't know if that's possible?

The other way of asking this would be - is there a way to take a "stream" and truncate its changeset history (everything older than a certain point).  But if the code is "composed" of the changeset delta's... that may preclude that.

Update 12/10/2018:  Received a suggestion for removing the content of old change sets, to keep the database small which may help performance. The change set still exists as a history information, but the content can no longer be recovered:

https://jazz.net/library/article/1006